# Why does explicitly changing the value of a variable not cause its alias to change?

Tags: python, alias

Say, for example, that I set `x = [1,2,3]`, and then set `temp = x`.

Then, because `x` and `temp` are referring to the same value, if we do `temp.reverse()`, both `temp` and `x` are reversed.

Why, then, if we set `x = [1,2,3]` and  set `temp = x` , and then `temp = [7,8,9]`, is `x` not still equal to `temp` (`x = [1,2,3]` and `temp = [7,8,9]`)? We've still modified `temp`, but unlike in the above example, the alias does not stick. Why is this?

Comment: No you did not modified the **object** `tmp` refers to, you modified the **reference** of `tmp`...

Comment: The object behind the variable `temp` is not modified by assignment to `temp`. The statement "`temp = some_new_value`" (re)binds the name `temp` to a new object, leaving the old object, if any, intact.

Comment: Changing by mutating (.reverse()) is different than changing by rebinding (x = ...).  See [Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) for more details.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I think I understand that. But why, when you're creating a clone, does changing the thing of which you made a clone, not affect the clone itself?

For example, if `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = a[:]`, and then we set `a.append(4)`, why is it that `b = [1,2,3]`? Surely, since `b` refers to `a[:]` which refers to `a`, changing `a` changes `a[:]` which changes `b`. Why is this not the case?

Comment: `a[:]` does not refer to a.  It used a to create an entirely new list that has no relationship to a.  Just like `2+2` is 4, and has no connection to 2 any more.